# Unable to remove some emojis from Tweets in Python

Tags: python, twitter

I have a data set of Tweets. I am trying to remove all the emojis and symbols from these Tweets. However, my code is not removing some of the emojis such as , ☠, ❤, ⭐ and other. How can I improve what have I tried or use another way to remove all these emojis from the Tweets? I have the Tweets in a pandas datagram.

```
 ########## How I tried
 emoji_pattern = re.compile("["
                           u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
                           u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
                           u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
                           u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
                           "]")

cleanedData['text'] = cleanedData['text'].str.replace(emoji_pattern, '')
```

> cleanedData.head(5).to_dict() // After removing emojis with the above

```
{'id': {0: 1042616899408945154, 1: 1042592536769044487, 2: 1042587702040903680, 3: 1042587263643930626, 4: 1042586780292276230}, 'month': {0: 9, 1: 9, 2: 9, 3: 9, 4: 9}, 'hour': {0: 3, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'text': {0: ' are red, violets are blue, if you want to buy us , here is a CLUE  Our  eye &amp; cheek palette is AL… ', 1: 'Is it too late now to say sorry   ', 2: ' Oh no! Please email your order # to social &amp; we can help . This is a newest offer!!', 3: " It's best applied with our buffer brush! \xa0", 4: ' DEAD '}, 'hasMedia': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'hasHashtag': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'followers_count': {0: 801745, 1: 801745, 2: 801745, 3: 801745, 4: 801745}, 'retweet_count': {0: 17, 1: 94, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0}, 'favourite_count': {0: 181, 1: 408, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 14}, 'sentiments': {0: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.949, 'pos': 0.051, 'compound': 0.0772}, 1: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 1.0, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': 0.0}, 2: {'neg': 0.1, 'neu': 0.634, 'pos': 0.266, 'compound': 0.5684}, 3: {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.64, 'pos': 0.36, 'compound': 0.6696}, 4: {'neg': 0.834, 'neu': 0.166, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.7213}}}
```

Comment: Do you have some examples of the tweets?

Comment: See the cleanedData.head(5).to_dict() . I updated above

Comment: See my answer - you will need to use it on the text part of your tweet object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you need from the dataset, you could try using a broader regex pattern, such as

```
cleaned_data['text'] = cleaned_data['text'].str.replace(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: replace() missing 1 required positional argument: 'repl'

Comment: Apologies - fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - no regex:

```
cleaned_text = u"\U0001F600 some words then symbol \U0001F6FF".encode('ascii', 'ignore')
.decode('utf8')
```

I'm assuming the symbols are found within a tweet

Answer (score 0):

Try the 'demoji' package in python

Comment: This is a pretty good answer. Please see the attached link to the suggested python library: https://pypi.org/project/demoji/

Answer (score 0):

I could remove all the emojis in the tweets dataset using regex as following

```
def deEmojify(text):
    regrex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # emoticons
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # transport & map symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # flags (iOS)
        u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U00002702-\U000027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U0001f937"
        u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
        u"\u2640-\u2642"
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\ufe0f"  # dingbats
        u"\u3030"
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regrex_pattern.sub(r'', text)

df['text'] = df['text'].apply(deEmojify)
```